# Azure Functions Python v2 - Azure Service Bus Queue - Decode Azure Service Bus Message to JSON

Tags: python, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I want to to decode a message from Azure Service Bus Queue to a json object in an Azure Function with Python v2.

At the moment I'm peeking at the messages.

This is my code so far:

```
app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="mytimer")
@app.schedule(schedule="0 */30 * * * *", arg_name="mytimer", run_on_startup=True) 
def procesReadings(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR)

    with servicebus_client:
        receiver = servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME)
        with receiver:
            received_msgs = receiver.peek_messages(max_message_count=5)
            for msg in received_msgs:
                logging.info(type(msg))
                logging.info(type(msg.message))
                logging.info(type(msg.application_properties))
```

The types are as follow:

1. `<class 'azure.servicebus._common.message.ServiceBusReceivedMessage'>`
2. `<class 'azure.servicebus._pyamqp._message_backcompat.LegacyMessage'>`
3. `<class 'dict'>`

When I log the msg and msg.message, I get the same output in terminal.

I'm trying to decode the msg to a json object or at least the msg.message to a json object.

I already tried:

```
message_decoded = json.loads(msg.message.decode('utf-8'))
message_decoded = json.loads(msg.decode('utf-8'))
```

But nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you share which type of message you are sending from service bus  for decoding?

Comment: The messages are coming from Chirpstack LoRaWAN Server

Answer (score 0):

> I want to to decode a message from Azure Service Bus Queue to a json object in an Azure Function with Python v2.

- Here, I have reproduced as per the requirement that the below code is to send the message to the queue. please check the code.

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage
 
 
app = func.FunctionApp()
 
@app.schedule(schedule="0 */2 * * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=True,
            use_monitor=False)
def timer_trigger(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    if myTimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')
 
connection_str = "your servicebus conn-string"
queue_name = "newqueue"
 
def send_message(message_body):
    try:
        # Create a ServiceBusClient using the connection string
        servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(connection_str)
 
        # Create a sender for the specified queue
        sender = servicebus_client.get_queue_sender(queue_name=queue_name)
 
        # Create a message
        message = ServiceBusMessage(message_body)
 
        # Send the message
        sender.send_messages(message)
 
        print(f"Message sent: {message_body}")
 
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
 
    finally:
        # Close the sender and the ServiceBusClient
        sender.close()
        servicebus_client.close()
 
# Example usage
message_body = "Hello, Azure Service Bus!"
send_message(message_body)
```

[image]

[image]

- The `msg` object you receive is an instance of `ServiceBusReceivedMessage`. To extract the message body as a JSON object, you need to access the `body` property of the message.
- Make sure package `pip install azure-servicebus`  has been installed.

**Function code:**

```py
import json
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient

CONNECTION_STR = "your_connection_string"
QUEUE_NAME = "your_queue_name"

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="mytimer")
@app.schedule(schedule="0 */30 * * * *", arg_name="mytimer", run_on_startup=True) 
def process_readings(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR)

    with servicebus_client:
        receiver = servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME)
        with receiver:
            received_msgs = receiver.peek_messages(max_message_count=5)
            for msg in received_msgs:
                logging.info(f"Received Message: {msg}")
                # Check if the message body is not empty
                if msg.body:
                    try:
                        # Decode the JSON payload
                        message_json = json.loads(next(msg.body).decode('utf-8'))
                        logging.info(f"Decoded Message JSON:\n{json.dumps(message_json, indent=2)}")
                    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                        logging.error(f"Error decoding JSON: {e}")
                else:
                    logging.warning("Received message with empty body.")
```

**Requirement.txt:**

```
azure-functions
azure-servicebus
```

Comment: When I try your code I get the following error:

`Exception: AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'decode' `

Comment: I have updated the above Solution, check once.